# Is iOS6 simulator buggy when deleting applications?

Tags: ios, simulator, ios6

Frequently, when I try to delete an app on the iOS 6 simulator that comes with Xcode 4.5, the simulator freezes. What I do is just long press on the app. Delete dialog doesn't come up and the icons keep on wiggling. Quitting and re-opening the simulator does not help to delete the app.

I've tried to delete the app's folder from /Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications folder. Sometimes this helps but sometimes even this doesn't delete the icon from the simulator.

This behavior is independent of the iOS version or the device model. It's the same whichever model/iOS I choose.

The only thing that helps is using the Reset Contents and Settings option of the simulator.

Do you experience the same frustration? If so, have you figured out a workaround besides resetting the simulator completely?

Comment: I have experienced this, but finally the delete dialog appeared. After a minute or so (the time it took me to google the problem, find this and read it).

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing with XCode 4.5.1 - Did you ever find a solution to this?

For me it only happens when running the 5.1 simulator from XCode 4.5.1. The 6.0 simulator does allow me to delete apps this way.

Comment: @MarkNorgren Unfortunately, the only thing that works for me is still the Reset Contents and Settings option :[ I'll update this question if I could find a solution. Please post your answer if you find it first :)

Comment: Please file a radar and post the rdar:// url here. If other people are having this issue, please also submit bugs and dup the radar number.

Comment: @AndrewPouliot OK, I filed a bug with ID: 12679338. I couldn't see how to get this bug's rdar:// url. If you know how to get it, please tell and I'll share it here.

Comment: @davsan You just put rdar:// in front of the bug id, so rdar://12679338

Comment: I waited for 6 seconds and it finally appears. Does the freeze happens every time or just when your system is busy? Try leaving only Xcode and simulator alone and running it and see if it is much smoother.

Comment: Strange thing is, I have experienced the same thing on my device a few days ago. I thought the device was stuck, pressing home/ sleep button did not help and after a minute the alertView  was finally visible, which allowed me to go on. Maybe it was a one-time problem, but I wonder if the problem is caused by the IOS or the simulator.

Comment: This is a clear bug in the iOS simulator and there are two valid workarounds (reset the simulator or delete the app in the file system). The OP doesn't like these answers but those are the only solutions.

Comment: Not a solution I like, but deleting the app in the file system seems like the only thing we have for now, except for resetting. So let's accept the answer @XJones mentions :]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've run into this as well and it only seems to be a problem for me when I have the simulator set to version = iOS 5.0 or iOS 5.1. In any case, what I did to delete my app w/o completely resetting the simulator is the following:

1. Quit iOS Simulator
2. In the Finder or Terminal, go to ~/Library/ApplicationSupport/iPhone Simulator/5.1
3. Delete the folder containing the app you want to remove from the simulator
4. Restart the simulator (or just Build + Run from XCode) and your app gone/freshly installed

In step #2, replace "5.1" with the iOS simulator version you want to remove your app from.

The OP mentioned that this solution didn't work. My guess is they did not do step #1. If you don't quit the simulator first, deleting the app folder may not be possible if the app is running in the simulator and won't visually show up until a restart anyway.

Comment: I'm using simulator version 6.0. And it is also not a good idea to delete app using finder. I can delete app in simulator but it will take more than one minute.

Comment: Whatever works for you, I'm giving the solution that works for me. There's nothing wrong with deleting the app from the finder. I know of no other workaround to a clear bug in the iOS simulator. I am using the same version of XCode and the iOS simulator as you. I have the iOS version set to 5.1 in the simulator to experience this problem. Your example path in your question shows that you are doing the same thing.

Comment: I'm the bounty giver not the question asker.

Comment: apologies, I missed that. FWIW, my motivation for answering this is to try and help, not the bounty. This is a particularly annoying bug on Apple's part.

Comment: En, yes! Just an annoying bug. But I can't give bounty to you. I'm sorry. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 8):

You can reset you simulator configuration from iOS Simulator-> Reset Content and Settings...
This will delete all your data on simulator

Comment: Yes, all data, including images in photo album. For most of the time we don't want to delete all data.

Comment: FWIW, this shouldn't have been down voted. It's a perfectly reasonable solution and does work, albeit with side effects.

Comment: @XJones The down vote is not by me. I've already known this way before his answer. And this has side effects. So I can't give bounty to him. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem with iPhone/iPad 6.0 simulator.  I have Lion and xcode 4.5.2 .
The way I solved it was after clicking on the X, to use menu to invoke slide to lock, then unlock it.  Then the delete msg box will appear and I can confirm the delete.

I sometimes had to rotate left or right before slide to lock would show after invoking the menu.

Answer (score 2):

This occours more if app is running on simulator . so first stop the application then delete the app. may save  your time

Comment: Yes, doesn't help me either.

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem, and the solution was to just long-click on the X button. Tapping it isn't enough to cause the delete dialog to appear. This bugged me for months!

Comment: This also can't solve the problem. It will still take a long time to delete one app.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 6.0 Simulator, I was facing the same issue. Tried holding the X for a while like 30 sec continuously, then got the "Delete Application" pop up. Finally I am able to delete app on iOS 6.0 Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

After click on cross button lock the simulator and then unlock it after that require pop up comes up and then delete it.